# Spinners with Text android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am looking forward to making a bible app with android studio, I have a plan, that I will make two spinners and button in horizontal linear layout one of the spinners to the names of the books and the second to the chapters and the button to convert from old testament to new testament, and below them scroll layout with text view that will show the text of the chapter of the book

example: to show the text of chapter 1 in Genesis book of the bible

1. I will choose first from books spinners Genesis book
2. after choosing the Genesis book, will appear the chapters of Genesis book be in the chapter spinner.
3. I will choose the 1 chapter from the second spinner ((chapters spinners))
4. after choosing the chapter, will appear the text of the chapter in the text view

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
  }
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
  }
});
```